# Chrome Inspect Element Autocomplete bug (delete letters as i type)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When I type a style in the CSS panel in Chrome developer tool, the developer tool deletes every 2nd or 3rd letter that I type. For example, if I try to type "border-bottom", I would end up with something like "brder-bttom" and it would be almost impossible to type fully unless I type amazingly fast or slow (one letter by one). **I think autocompletion is trying to override my input because when there is no suggestion, I can type fine.**

If anyone knows a solution or has the same bug, please let me know.
I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.97.

Comment: I am having the same issue and it's killing me. I really don't want to go back to Firefox and Firebug but this really slows me down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a manifestation of http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133789 that I've never had a chance to reproduce (and it's only the second report so far).

We had this bug about a year ago, due to the regressed behavior in Chromium, but the offending change was reverted. Please comment on the said issue by pasting the contents of your chrome://version/ and perhaps some steps to reproduce this.